# gphoto2 / Canon 700D Liveview low Framerate / laggy picture

Tags: canon, camera

I tried streaming the liveview from my Canon EOS 700D through `gphoto2` and `ffmpeg` for the first time. ([See this](https://www.crackedthecode.co/how-to-use-your-dslr-as-a-webcam-in-linux/#hardware-needed), and [this](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback)) It works, but the picture I see in VLC (and other apps) is very laggy. The perceived framerate is very low. (Computer: Thinkpad E495 / Ryzen 7, so pretty new)

Is this a limitation of the 700D, or can I optimize this with other parameters? Does gphoto2 tell the Canon which resolution to output, or is it fixed? The camera settings don't seem to make a difference.

This is the command I used:

```
gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

**edit:** Maybe the framerate can be increased with ffmpeg hardware acceleration? I didn't manage to get that working yet, with my onboard ATI radeon chip.